# Merging tags (from a list of strings) together

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

If in list[1] I have two strings, containing two XML tags:

```
<example> this is cool</example>
```

and

```
<example> this is cooler! </example>
```

how could I merge both tags into a single one so it looks like this:

```
<example> this is cool this is cooler! </example>
```

So when I do print(list[1]) I get:

```
<example> this is cool this is cooler! </example>
```

Comment: So, you have a list with two strings?

Comment: @brandizzi I have a list with 1 element, inside that element there is a single string "<example> this is cool</example> <example> this is cooler! </example> "

Comment: If you say you have "tags", I ask what kind of tags? BeautifulSoup? ElementTree? Minidom? What xml/html parser are you using?

Comment: You can use for example regex to extract contents of both tags, then concatenate the two extracted pieces and then wrap it in a single tag.

Comment: @Rawing they are XML tags. :)

Comment: Sure, they are XML tags, but are they already parsed? Or are they still strings? Do you know what parsing is?

Comment: @MirekE could you show me an example?

Comment: @brandizzi they are just strings. :)

Comment: @Jorge have you tried anything yet ... If it was me I would start with `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` or `import lxml`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have been trying with BeautifulSoup, but I haven't gotten this to work.

Comment: import re
result = re.sub("<example>(.+)</example><example>(.+)</example>", "<example>\\1\\2</example>", searchText)
Obviously, the regex may be more complicated depending on what you know about the contents of the string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to find the *tag name* and the *text* of both XML elements. To do that, the best thing to do is to *parse* the elements.

So, you have a list like this one, right?

```
>>> l = ['<example>this is cool</example>', '<example>this is cooler</example>']
```

First, let's *parse* it (in this case with `lxml`):

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> elements = [lxml.etree.fromstring(s) for s in l]
```

Now we have a list with two elements. From these elements, we can take their tag names...

```
>>> elements[0].tag
'example'
```

...and their text contents:

```
>>> elements[0].text
'this is cool'
>>> elements[1].text
'this is cooler'
```

Well, we can create a new *parsed* element of the same tag as the first one:

```
>>> new_element = new_element = lxml.etree.Element(elements[0].tag)
```

Now, we set the text of this new element to the concatenation of the two previous ones:

```
>>> new_element.text = elements[0].text + elements[1].text
```

Now, we get the string representation from the element object:

```
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(new_element)
b'<example>this is coolthis is cooler</example>'
```

Comment: I have a  list with a simple element:' <example>this is cool</example>' AND '<example>this is cooler</example>' are both list[1] there could be any number of '<example></example>' tags within list[1]

Comment: Hmm... Can't you see how to adapt the code below to your situation?

Comment: not when there can be any number of <example></example> tags

Comment: Besides that, can you understand what the code below does? Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, it makes sense. :)

Comment: Well, then, instead of getting the two text values, create with the text of all elements (e.g. with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and then concatenate them (e.g. with the [join method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)). I know this is not a complete answer but hey! you understood how to parse XML, it is not that hard to understand how to concatenate a list of strings :)